# create date between scope in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, time

I have a model with attributes 'date_starting' and 'date_ending'. I want to create a scope in my model that indicates if the model is within the date start and date end range using Time.now.

something like

```
scope :activeAtDate, lambda{ |date = Date.today| where("? BETWEEN date_starting AND date_ending", date) }
```

I used this of a different post but as a newbie, I am having difficulty making this work.

update:

controller

```
        @current = Guide.activeAtDate
```

Thanks,

Comment: i added my controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query logic is reversed, you have to find the bounds for each date_* field.
You can do it as follows

```
scope :active_at_date, lambda {
  where("date_starting < :date and date_ending > :date", date: Date.today )
}
```

there is no need in providing a parameter to your lambda. Because the parameter is always the same.

If you needed the date to be changeable you would rewrite it as

```
scope :active_at_certain_date, lambda { |date|
  where("date_starting < :date and date_ending > :date", date: date )
}
```